# Grafana Windows Exporter Dashboard CPU Load graph up to 2.0

Tags: prometheus, grafana, cpu-usage, windows-explorer

Using [Windows Exporter Dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/2129) I get strange result for CPU Usage. The red area spans to 2.0 value of X-Axis all the way:

[image]

But if I click on a single metric, it looks right:

**dpc**

[image]

**idle**

[image]

**interrupt**

[image]

**privileged**

[image]

**user**

[image]

The query for the graph is this:

```
sum by (mode) (rate(windows_cpu_time_total{instance=~"$server"}[5m]))
```

What is the reason it looks like that for all 5 metrics (1st image)?
Is it a feature that makes **user** graph inverted? If so how is this done and why 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a query for each mode:

```
avg(irate(windows_cpu_time_total{mode="idle", job=~"windows_exporter_test",instance=~"localhost:9182"}[5m])) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the following working for me (frequency, including idle upto you)

```
avg by (mode) (rate(windows_cpu_time_total{instance=~"$server", mode!="idle"}[10s])) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct %CPU load, you should divide with the number of logical CPU's

I am doing it like this:

```
sum by (mode) (rate(windows_cpu_time_total{instance=~"$server", mode!="idle"}[5m])) * 100 / scalar(windows_cs_logical_processors{instance=~"$server"})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).